# "Прямо зараз" чи "просто зараз"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Яка форма є правильною: *прямо зараз* чи *просто зараз* (у контексті *не зволікайте*, *зробіть це негайно*)?

Обидва варіанти добре шукаються в Google (але *просто зараз* - втричі частіше).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По-моєму, обидва варіанти цілком підходять:

> **[ПРО́СТО](http://sum.in.ua/s/prosto)**
>
> <…>
>
> **3.** *у знач[енні] підсил[ювальнох] част[ки].* Уживається для підкреслення значення якого-небудь слова або всього речення. <…> *Дома там у нього *просто* чудеса…* (Олесь Гончар, Тронка, 1963, 28).
>
> <…>
>
> ---
>
> **[ПРЯ́МО](http://sum.in.ua/s/prjamo)**, *присл[івник]*.
>
> <…>
>
> **3.** Безпосередньо, без проміжних ланок. <…>
>   // Відразу, негайно. <…>
>   // Якраз, точно, саме. <…>
>
> <…>
>
> **6.** *у знач[енні] підсил[ювальнох] част[ки], розм[овне]*. Уживається для підкреслення значення якого-небудь слова або всього речення; просто. <…>

Але я б усе-таки рекомендував ***[са́ме](http://sum.in.ua/s/same)** зараз*.

P.S.: Але якщо вважати, що це 6-те значення слова *прямо*, а не 3-тє, то варто перед словом *прямо* надавати перевагу іншим варіантам (*просто*, *саме*), бо це (6-те) значення слова *прямо* розмовне.

Comment: @Yola, чисто суб'єктивно _саме_ мені подобається більше. І такого словосполучення (і навіть окремого слова) нема в російській, отже є ризик, що про нього частіше забуватимуть. І в переліку значень там майже кожне підходить (а для _просто/прямо_ — лише 1-2 з багатьох, причому доволі специфічні; створюється враження, що для _саме_ це основне значення, а для _просто/прямо_ — неосновне, майже переносне).